# Changing LEDs on X-Touch Mini – Mackie Control (MC Mode)

Tags: java, midi, receiver

I have a Behringer X-Touch Mini [(MIDI Documentation)](https://media.music-group.com/media/PLM/data/docs/P0B3M/X-TOUCH%20MINI_QSG_WW.pdf) for which I want to control the LEDs.

The MIDI input is already working, but I want to send the correct LED messages to the controller. The MIDI controller is in `MC Mode` (Mackie Control emulation mode).

What's the correct data I need to send so the LEDs change?

I've tried this:

```
ShortMessage myMsg = new ShortMessage();
try {

    //command /channel /data1 /data2
    myMsg.setMessage(8, 1, 27, 127);

} catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
long timeStamp = -1;
Receiver rcvr = null;
try {
    rcvr = MidiSystem.getReceiver();
} catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
rcvr.send(myMsg, timeStamp);
rcvr.close();
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: , but i want to send the correct led positions to the controller

Comment: That is not a problem, it is your goal.

Comment: i do not know how to send the data correctly to the device.. i also tried different values in the setMessage method.

Answer (score 4):

The X-Touch Mini's documentation for changing LED values works as expected only for `Standard Mode`.

Mackie Control emulation is meant so that X-Touch can be used with every music program (legacy). Here's the only [Mackie Control documentation](https://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=101328) I have found.

The original Mackie Control only had 11 LEDs for Knobs, therefore 2 LEDs won't be controllable in the X-Touch. See 'V-Pot rings' in the MC documentation (values are in hex).

---

**Button LEDs**

Note:

- Same as the input note when pressing down the button.
- 40-45, 84-95

Velocity:

- 0 = OFF
- 1 = BLINK
- 127 = ON

Example:

```
ShortMessage(NOTE_ON, 0, note, velocity);
```

As noted by [CL.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436229/1165976) use the constant `NOTE_ON` (144). You are currently providing `8` which is an invalid command.

**Knob LEDs**

CC (Control Change):

- 48-55

Value:

- 0 = OFF
- 1-11 = SINGLE
- 17-27 = TRIM
- 33-43 = FAN
- 49-54 = SPREAD

Example:

```
ShortMessage(CONTROL_CHANGE, 0, cc, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ShortMessage` class has fields such as [NOTE_ON](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/ShortMessage.html#NOTE_ON) that help you construct a message with the correct values.

And "CC" would be a control change message.

And you have to use the channel/controller/note/velocity numbers specified in the documentation. For example, to light the LED on the last button, you would have to use note 15 and velocity 1.

Comment: i do not understand where i can set note and velocity.
short messages has following parameters ..
`ShortMessage(int command, int channel, int data1, int data2)`

Comment: Read the [specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/the-midi-1-0-specification).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the LEDs can be done by using these parameters:

Command: Note On = 9

Data 1: Key = 0-15

Data 2: 0 = Led off, 1 = Led on, 2 Led blink